# Compare setOnAction event with Keycode

Tags: javafx, listener, actionlistener, keycode

Is there a way to compare a setOnAction event with Keycode (like Up and Down Arrow)?

Here is my sample:

```
 comboBox.setOnAction(e ->{
//compare event key with KeyCode up or down
                if(e.getSource().equals(KeyCode.DOWN)) {
                    // do stuff
                } else {
                comboBox.hide();
                // do some other stuff
                }
            });
```

Comment: What does is mean to "compare a setOnAction event with Keycode"? This doesn't make sense. Can you explain what you are actually trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
comboBox.setOnKeyPressed(ke->{
    if(ke.getCode().equals(KeyCode.DOWN)){
        // do stuff
    }
    else{
        comboBox.hide();
        // do some other stuff
    }
})
```